# Need this regex to check for 3 decimal places?

Tags: regex

I have :

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

But need it to allow only up to 3 decimal places. So allowed values are:

```
+10.123

-10.123

10.123

10

+10

-10

10.1

10.12
```

Not allowed:

```
10.1234

10.123%
```

Advice / suggested expression mods appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here: `^[-+]?\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ^[+-]?\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$
```

Explanation:
[image]

See it here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/BbCBL5pQWLxsD4a6

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
   Match a single character present in the list below [+-]?
     ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, 
                    giving back as needed (greedy)
     +- matches a single character in the list +- (case sensitive)
   \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
      + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
                     giving back as needed (greedy)
   1st Capturing Group (\.\d{1,3})?
     ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, 
                    giving back as needed (greedy)
     \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
     \d{1,3} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
     {1,3} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, 
                        giving back as needed (greedy)
   $ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Explanation From: [https://regex101.com/]

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was creating the sample, before your comment. Only thing that I changed in mine that was originally wrong was the {0,3} to {1,3}.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now there is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The online site generates the same picture for both.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you can test on the link.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `*` and `+` metacharacters, which specify *unlimited* repetition, regex allows you to place specific limits on the number of matches with the `{a,b}` construct. Here, `a` is the minimum required number of matches, and `b` is the maximum. Both `a` and `b` are *inclusive*.

Since you need to match at least one and at most three digits, you need to replace `\d+` with `\d{1,3}`:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]\d*(\.\d{1,3})?$
```

**Optimization:** With a working regex in hand, you can optimize by replacing `[0-9]` with another `\d`, and "folding" it into `\d*` by using `\d+`:

```
^[+-]?\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$
```

Comment: Really appreciated yours answer as well, just can tick 2 answers !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`^[+-]{0,1}\d*?(\.{0,1}\d{0,3})?$` should work

see https://regex101.com/r/P6DBrW/1/ for Explanation of the regexp

Comment: `{0,3}` would let you match `10.` with zero decimal digits. OP's regex does not allow that.

Answer (score -1):

```
^(?!0\d)\d*         
(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon. Please provide an explanation and not just a raw code dump.

Comment: Please add additional context for why & how this answers the question.